# SharePoint 2007 - SP2 & October 2010 CU installation

Tags: 2007, upgrade

In continuation with my earlier question on SP2 upgrade.  I also wanted to upgrade my servers onto October 2010 CU.

So the upgrade path would be to first install SP2 and then install the October 2010 CU. I am planning to do it on the same time (day).

My question is can I install both the Installation Bits onto server and run Configuration wizard just once ?

If I am not wrong,  I will have to install the updates onto all WFEs and Application Server?

Thanks for your help...

Regards,
Sudhir Kesharwani

Answer (score 1):

Yes you only need to run the configuration wizard once (on each server)

Yes you have to install all packages on all servers

When you install an update for MOSS you have to install the corresponding update for WSS first.

It might be a good idea to read though (and follow) [Deploy software updates for Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263467%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Per,  so while upgrading to SP2 I will have to first install WSS 3.0 SP2 and then MOSS 2007 SP2?  Is that the case ?  or you were refereeing to older version of WSS (2.0) and SPS 2003?

Comment: I just checked it's only for SP2010 they have changed the latest upgrades so you don't have to install Foundation before Server. So you should apply WSS SP2, MOSS SP2, WSS CU, MOSS CU and then run config wizard